# Filling area under line with lowest value

Tags: plotting, filling

How to use Fill but only under the line which has the lowest value on plot? Consider following code:

```
data = Table[#, {x,-5,10,1}]&/@{{x, 2 x + 3}, {x, 5 x + 2}, {x, -3 x + 20}, {x, 5}}
ListLinePlot[data]
```

Which gives a plot:

[image]

And that's how it should look:

[image]

Since the plots will **not always be the same**, the bottom lines are changing so **I can't just hardcode it**

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xylst = {{x, 2 x + 3}, {x, 5 x + 2}, {x, -3 x + 20}, {x, 5}};

data = Table[#, {x, -5, 10, 1}] & /@ xylst;

ylst = xylst[[All, -1]];

celst = Table[ConditionalExpression[f, f == Min[ylst]], {f, ylst}];

Show[ListLinePlot @ data, 
    Plot[celst, {x, -5, 10}, Filling -> Bottom]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `ylst` and `celst` with `Plot`:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Join[ylst, celst], {x, -5, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97] /@ Range[4], 
 Filling -> Thread[Range[5, 8] -> Bottom]]
```

[image]

**Update:** If we have access only to `data` (not the functions used to generate `data`):

```
iFlst = Interpolation /@ data;

cElst = Table[ConditionalExpression[f[x], 
    f[x] == Min[Through@iFlst@x]], {f, iFlst}];

Plot[Evaluate @ Join[Through @ iFlst @ x, cElst], 
 {x, Min @ data[[All, All, 1]], Max @ data[[All, All, 1]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ iFlst]),
 Filling -> Thread[Length @ iFlst + Range[Length @ iFlst] -> Bottom]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Works perfect. Thank you!